# Get the "line item" description field in Invoice -Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am learning netsuite,

I need to get the line item description in invoice module,If the description contains Tax, then I need to change "term" field value to "Taxable term"

**How to fetch the "description" of the particular line item and update its "term", if description field value contains "tax"?**

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to be followed are as follows:

1. Get the sublist ID
2. Get the number of lines present (LineCount)
3. Use the **FOR LOOP** to iterate within those lines, and make changes accordingly.
4. After making the changes, commit the line
5. Finally, save the record

```
//Loading the record - Invoice 
var recordInvoice = record.load({
   type: record.Type.INVOICE,
   id: 276
});
```

So firstly, you will require to fetch the ID of that sublist containing the 'description' field. (In most of the cases its `item`, I'll go with it).

Next, get the number of lines.

```
var numLines = record.getLineCount({
 sublistId: 'item'
});
```

Using FOR Loop, iterate through the lines. **Make sure you select the line and use correct syntax**

```
for(var j=0; j<numLines; j++) {

   record.selectLine({
      sublistId: 'item',
      line: j
   )};

   var descriptionValue = record.getCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: 'item',
      fieldId: 'description' //Try finding this value using &xml=t
   });

   if(descriptionValue) {

      record.setCurrentSublistValue({
         sublistId: 'item',
         fieldId: 'yourfield',
         value: 'your value'
      });

   }

   record.commitLine({
      sublistId: 'item'
   });
}

record.save();
```

Try this out, let me know if you face any issues in the comments.